# the smallest field containing the class $\mathscr{C}= \{(0,1 / 2],(1 / 4,2 / 3],(3 / 5,1]\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, probability-theory, measure-theory

We have known that in general the smallest field containing $k$ subsets has, in the general case, size $2^{2^k}$.

However, in this question, follows the above result, we will have $2^{2^3} = 256$ elements in the smallest field $\mathscr{F}$. How can we represent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Given $A,B,C$ consider $A\cap B \cap C, A^{c} \cap B\cap C, A\cap B^{c}\cap C, A\cap B\cap C^{c}, A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c}, A^{c}\cap B\cap C^{c}, A^{c}\cap B^{c}\cap C$ and $A^{c}\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c}$. (Some of these may be empty). The field generated by $A,B,C$ is the collection of all possible unions of these sets. In our case you get $(0,\frac   1 4], (\frac 1 4, \frac 1 2], (\frac 1 2, \frac 3 5](\frac  3 5, \frac 2  3]$ and $(\frac  2 3,1]$. The field generated consists of all possible unions of these (including the empty set). There are $2^{5}$ sets in it.

Comment: Thanks so much! But I am confused that why in this case the number of sets is $2^5$ instead of $2^{2^3}$?

Comment: The actual number depends on how many of the sets I mentioned are non-empty. You don't always get $2^{2^{3}}$ **distinct** sets. ($2^{2^{3}}$ is the maximum). @香结丁

Comment: Got! I appreciate your generous help!